# Howto add third-party application to Bitnami OpenProject?

Tags: apache, tomcat, bitnami, openproject

I have a manual installation of a Bitnami application

```
http ://project.url/openproject
```

Beside that, I installed the scm-server via apt-get, which worked fine.

However, when trying to access scm-server via

```
http ://project.url:8080/
```

I get an error 503 from the Bitnami apache.

So, my question is how I can modify the Bitnami apache in a way that it makes my scm-server application accessible, for instance, via

```
http ://project.url/scm
```

Thanks a lot for your hints! (I had to put the spaces into the urls because I was hindered on saving this post otherwise...)

-Hardy